# Gremlin query group the aggregated results count for multiple persons

Tags: where-clause, aggregate, gremlin

I'm trying to create a Gremlin query which would select persons whos policies are in statuses - `STARTED` and `CANCELLED`, and that checks whether policies count, in given status, are more than or equal to `2`. If both of these statuses are not present, the person is NOT selected. Each person can have multiple policies in given statuses.

I have created the following Gremlin query (incomplete):

```
g.V().hasLabel('Person_ID').as('p')\
.out('has_pol').hasLabel('Policy_ID').as('pol').dedup()\
    .local(\
        __.aggregate('motor_pol').values('status_code')\
    ).groupCount().by()
```

That produces the following output:

```
==>[IN_PROGRESS:1,CANCELLED:3,STARTED:3]
```

When I move the `.groupCount().by()` inside the `.local()` function, it still selects incorrectly:

```
==>[CANCELLED:1]
==>[STARTED:1]
==>[CANCELLED:1]
==>[STARTED:1]
==>[IN_PROGRESS:1]
==>[STARTED:1]
==>[CANCELLED:1]
```

**Expected:** I need somehow to count the policy statuses for each person, so that I can select only the persons who have - two started and two cancelled policies (Person 1), something like this:

```
p1:[started:2, cancelled:2]
p2:[in_progress:1]
p3:[started:1, cancelled:1]
```

How to correctly use the `.local()` function to be able to apply count for each person's policies?

Here is the query that generates test data:

```
graph = TinkerGraph.open()
g = graph.traversal()

v_person1 = g.addV('Person_ID').property(id, 1).property('name', 'Antonio').property('age', 29).next()
v_person1_pol1 = g.addV('Policy_ID').property(id, 11).property('start_date', 1431666765569).property('cancel_date', '').property('status_code', 'STARTED').next()
g.addE('has_pol').from(v_person1).to(v_person1_pol1).property(id, 111)

v_person1_pol2 = g.addV('Policy_ID').property(id, 12).property('start_date', 1421666765569).property('cancel_date', 1439666765569).property('status_code', 'CANCELLED').next()
g.addE('has_pol').from(v_person1).to(v_person1_pol2).property(id, 112)

v_person1_pol3 = g.addV('Policy_ID').property(id, 13).property('start_date', 1421566765569).property('cancel_date', '').property('status_code', 'IN_PROGRESS').next()
g.addE('has_pol').from(v_person1).to(v_person1_pol3).property(id, 113)

v_person1_pol4 = g.addV('Policy_ID').property(id, 14).property('start_date', 1421566765569).property('cancel_date', '').property('status_code', 'STARTED').next()
g.addE('has_pol').from(v_person1).to(v_person1_pol4).property(id, 114)

v_person1_pol5 = g.addV('Policy_ID').property(id, 15).property('start_date', 1421566765569).property('cancel_date', '1429666765569').property('status_code', 'CANCELLED').next()
g.addE('has_pol').from(v_person1).to(v_person1_pol5).property(id, 115)

v_person2 = g.addV('Person_ID').property(id, 2).property('name', 'Bob').property('age', 35).next()
v_person2_pol1 = g.addV('Policy_ID').property(id, 21).property('start_date', 1431666765569).property('cancel_date', '').property('status_code', 'IN_PROGRESS').next()
g.addE('has_pol').from(v_person2).to(v_person2_pol1).property(id, 221)

v_person3 = g.addV('Person_ID').property(id, 3).property('name', 'Paula').property('age', 22).next()
v_person3_pol1 = g.addV('Policy_ID').property(id, 31).property('start_date', 1431666765569).property('cancel_date', '').property('status_code', 'STARTED').next()
g.addE('has_pol').from(v_person3).to(v_person3_pol1).property(id, 331)

v_person3_pol2 = g.addV('Policy_ID').property(id, 32).property('start_date', 1421666765569).property('cancel_date', 1439666765569).property('status_code', 'CANCELLED').next()
g.addE('has_pol').from(v_person3).to(v_person3_pol2).property(id, 332)
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the sample graph. That really helps. It's going to take a little time to study all of this and suggest a solid answer, but you can often solve these types of situation using a nested group. The outer group would be the person ID in your case. The inner group would be the label/count groups. A simple example might be `gremlin> g.V(1,2,3).group().by(id).by(group().by(label).by(out().count()))
==>[1:[airport:242],2:[airport:41],3:[airport:93]]   `

Comment: You could then mix in some either pre or post group creation filtering to throw away cases where certain label/count pairs do not exist.

Comment: @KelvinLawrence thanks for the response! I implemented a solution that seems to be working, although I took a bit different approach. Currently checking whether it really works as expected.

Comment: Sounds good. Hopefully it works well! If not we can continue the discussion here and explore some options.

Comment: I went ahead and added an answer that uses nested `group` and `groupCount` steps, in case it is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding of the sample graph, you could do something like this.

```java
g.V().
  hasLabel('Person_ID').as('p').
  out('has_pol').hasLabel('Policy_ID').
  group().
    by(select('p').id()).
    by(groupCount().by('status_code')).unfold()
```

which when run in the Gremlin Console, produces:

```
==> 1={IN_PROGRESS=1, CANCELLED=2, STARTED=2}
==> 2={IN_PROGRESS=1}
==> 3={CANCELLED=1, STARTED=1}
```